# Add a module by makefile or manually

Tags: makefile, ocaml, menhir, ocaml-dune

I have a big project built with traditional makefile. I would like to add a mechanism of error handling like [this project](https://gitlab.inria.fr/fpottier/menhir/-/tree/master/demos/calc-syntax-errors) to my project.

In the sample project, a module `UnitActionsParser` is generated by the following rules of dune:

```
;; The following two rules create a copy of the file parser.mly named
;; unitActionsParser.mly. This is a copy of the grammar where the semantic
;; actions have been removed and replaced with unit values. It is compiled
;; by Menhir's table back-end to obtain the module UnitActionsParser.

;; The use of [--external-tokens Parser] is required for the two parsers
;; to share a single [token] type. This makes them usable with the same
;; lexer.

(rule
  (action
    (with-stdout-to unitActionsParser.mly
      (run menhir
        %{dep:parser.mly}
        --only-preprocess-u
))))

(menhir
  (modules unitActionsParser)
  (flags --table --external-tokens Parser)
)
```

At the moment, the `makefile` of my project contains like:

```
OCAMLYACC=      $(OCAMLPREFIX)menhir -v

%.ml %.mli: %.mly
    $(OCAMLYACC) $*.mly
```

So now, I'm wondering how to build such a `UnitActionsParser` module. The best would be to modify my `makefile`, does anyone know how to do that? Otherwise, we could also add it manually in the first place. I tried in the command line `$ menhir --table --external-tokens Parser`, but it returned me `Usage: menhir <options> <filenames>`. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the rule directly to your Makefile. The direct translation of the `dune` file would be

```
unitActionsParser.mly: parser.mly
    $(OCAMLYACC) --only-preprocess-u $< > $@
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. How could I translate the `... --table --external-tokens ...` part of dune to makefile?

Comment: Menhir expects a filename and not a module name: `menhir --table --external-tokens Parser.ml`.